# Anagram finder in C displays correct and incorrect outcome?

Tags: c, logic, anagram

I'm new to C and trying to make an anagram finder, but it doesn't work correctly and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. It works by counting the number of letters in 2 different strings using 2 seperate integer arrays named `counter1` and `counter2`. It's then supposed to compare the values in each counter and check for any mismatches, but for some reason it prints both possible outcomes instead of the correct one. Any help appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  //Letter counter for each string
  int counter1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
  int counter2[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

  // Strings to be checked
  char s1[] = "abcd";
  char s2[] = "dcba";

  //Checks letter count in string 1
  
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
    if (s1[i] == ' ') {
      continue; }
    
    else if (s1[i] == 'a') {
      counter1[0] += 1; }

    else if (s1[i] == 'b') {
      counter1[1] += 1; }

    else if (s1[i] == 'c') {
      counter1[2] += 1; }

    else (s1[i] == 'd'); {
     counter1[3] += 1; }
    
  }

  // Checks letter count in string 2

   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++) {
    if (s2[i] == ' ') {
      continue; }
    
    else if (s2[i] == 'a') {
      counter2[0] += 1; }

    else if (s2[i] == 'b') {
      counter2[1] += 1; }

    else if (s2[i] == 'c') {
      counter2[2] += 1; }

    else (s2[i] == 'd'); {
      counter2[3] += 1; }
    
  }

  //Checks for mismatches in the letter counters 

  int flag = 0;
  int counterLen = sizeof(counter1)/sizeof(int);

  for (int i = 0; i < counterLen; i++ ) {
   if (counter1[i] != counter2[i]) {
     flag++; }

  }
    
  //Tells user if it's an anagram or not

  if (flag == 0) {
    printf("Anagram!"); }

  else (flag != 0); {
    printf("Not Anagram!"); }


}
```

Comment: Looks closely at this line: `else (flag != 0); {`

Comment: @EugeneSh. When i run it without the semi colon it gives me syntax error?

Comment: Look *more* closely...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I genuinely don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: You are missing `if` after `else`. It helps reading the code aloud. Or, as @Vlad  is suggesting down there, you don't need the second condition, as these are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @lukimari444 Remove the condition expression in the else part of the if statement.

Comment: I see. I thought it would work with `else`. I didn't realise you had to use `else if` when there's only 2 outcomes

Comment: @lukimari444 You don't. You can do either, but you just don't do it correctly. `else` alone does not take conditions.

Comment: .. and the other `else` lines. That issue aside, it seems this will only work for the `"abcd"` string? I suspect you'll need a more robust anagram finder than that. Consider a loop that compares the first char of `s1` to the last char of `s2`, then second char of `s1` to second-to-last char of `s2`, etc. As soon as you find one that doesn't match, no anagram. If you get all the way thru and it all matches, you have an anagram.

Comment: @yano This one was just a prototype sort of. i was going to expand on it after I'd got the basic premise down, so that it could take user input and use the whole alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if (s1[i] == 'c') {
      /* irrelevant 1 */ }

    else (s1[i] == 'd'); {
     /*  irrelevant 2 */ }
```

Does the code from "irrelevant 1" in case `s1[i] == 'c'`.

Otherwise it does `(s1[i] == 'd');`,
by evaluating a boolean expression and ignoring the result, because it is not used for anything, especially not for an `if`, because there is none.

Then it unconditionally does the code in "irrelevant 2". You have that non-pattern at least three times in your shown code.
I assume that the "unconditionally" results one way or another (sorry, not going into details there, because what you seem to actually be asking is what you missed...) in your "it prints both possible outcomes" observation.

Comment: Oh.. it's another one. So it is not typo as I though, but a systematic mistake.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Probably another at least two. By the way, I hope you see that I was thinking in parallel and not copying your input. Though I now realise there are similarities.

Comment: Sure, but even if you are, I have no problem with that, as I am usually lazy to write answers and someone should :)

Comment: @Yunnosch thankyou for your input. I've experimented with more `else` statements and I understand it much better now